# How does mobile switching work in a vs.net 2012 ASP.NET Web Forms Site project

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm in the early stages of investigating how to support a mobile set of pages in an ASP.NET Web Forms Site project.

In previous projects using MVC and Razor we would simply have a .mobile.cshtml version of the page and the ViewEngine would handle the switching between desktop and mobile versions of the page on the server (so for example index.cshtml would be served for a desktop browser and index.mobile.cshtml for mobile).

I had thought that something similar would be in place for web forms projects and to make sure fired up Visual Studio 2012, created an ASP.NET Web Forms site project and voila the template had created both a Site.Master and a Site.Mobile.Master and even included a ViewSwitcher.ascx. However when browsing to the site using either Chrome with the user agent set to one of the mobile strings or using the Electric Plum IPhone simulator I'm always ending up with the desktop version of the page.

I've done some debugging and had a look at the DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes collection and there is a Mobile provider and a default provider listed, so I'm a little confused as to what else is required to get the mobile version being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Neil did you look at the CSS file in the project? The @media tag allows your to write css to style on a device that is smaller.

/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

//styles here

}

Comment: Hello Tony, Yeah I could use a responsive design type approach, in fact it would be my preferred approach however the project involves offering a mobile solution for an existing website. We could just code a mobile one from scratch, however I like the idea of leveraging the same solution and having the desktop and mobile pages sit side by side on the server and then get rendered to the client based on the browser. With MVC supporting this through the .mobile.cshtml type approach and the project template having put in place similar things for aspx I'm stumped as to my lack of success.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same Problem. We needed some time to figure out, that you need to open the page with the URLRewrite-URL. Try to open 
`http://mymachine/myApplication/default`
instead of 
`http://mymachine/myApplication/default.aspx`

Best regards,
Nico